# MKAnnotiation dissapear after moving map

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a map with annotiation on it. But when i move the map the annotiation dissapeared.

What can i do that the annotiation not dissapeared?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your annotation data is nil or changed in some way. From what I recall, when you move around the map the annotations are reloaded, so if they don't exist they will seem to disappear. When you stop moving they may reappear, but that's a residual effect.